# How does one successfully connect to the TFS 2010 workitem store?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I've tried two ways of connecting to the workitemstore for the TFS server we're running.  Attempt A was to connect to the configuration server and use `GetService<WorkItemStore>()` method.  This always returns null.

Attempt B was to connect to the TfsTeamProjectCollection and use the `GetService<WorkItemStore>()` method or pass the project collection into the WorkItemStore constructor.  On attempt B, I get an exception stating "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."  The only info I can find on that seems to indicate some permissions problem, but I've confirmed I'm authenticated as a user with read access to the whole project collection and I connect and meddle appropriately via VS 2011 dev preview.

Here's how I'm connecting...

```
    public TfsConfigurationServer GetConfigurationServer()
    {
        Uri tfsUri = new Uri(configs.TfsUri);
        TfsConfigurationServer server = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri, credProvider);
        server.Authenticate();
        if (server.HasAuthenticated == false)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You can't authenticate against the tfs instance.");
        return server;
    }

    public TfsTeamProjectCollection GetProjectCollectionInstance(string projectCollectionName)
    {
        Uri tfsUri = new Uri(configs.TfsUri + "/" + projectCollectionName);         
        TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri, credProvider);
        collection.Authenticate();
        if (collection.HasAuthenticated == false)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You can't authenticate against the tfs instance.");
        return collection;
    }
```

and here's how I'm trying to get the WorkItemStore (silly code to illustrate the problem)...

```
    public WorkItemProvider()
    {
        if (workItems == null)
            workItems = ServerProvider.ServerInstance.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        if (workItems == null)
            workItems = ServerProvider.ProjectCollectionInstance.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        if (workItems == null)
            workItems = new WorkItemStore(ServerProvider.ProjectCollectionInstance);
        if (workItems == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("Couldn't load work item store.");
    }
```

I'm not on the same domain as the server, but I'm authenticating as a domain user with an ICredentialsProvider and I've confirmed I'm authenticated as that user.  Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Additional info: The same code works fine on a computer in our domain using windows auth and impersonation.  I guess I can't do this from outside the domain?  I can from Visual Studio, so that doesn't make sense.  Maybe if I could impersonate the domain user even though I'm not on the domain?

Answer (score 2):

Check if this does what you need:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

namespace GetsWorkItem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://<TFS>:8080/tfs/<COLLECTION>"));
            WorkItemStore workItemStore= (WorkItemStore) teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof (WorkItemStore));

            WorkItem workItem = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(1234);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works in a console app (once I add authentication), doesn't work in my web app.  Same error as attempt B in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this article](http://roadtoalm.com/2011/11/04/tfs-api-workitemstore-is-null-and-throws-nullreferenceexception/) might be able to answer your question. It says that if you instantiate your WorkItemStore in a slightly different way, you'll get a different exception:

`System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for ‘Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore’ threw an exception. —> System.IO.FileLoadException: Mixed mode assembly is built against version ‘v2.0.50727′ of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.`

The fix is a simple web.config change, by adding the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps! Worked for me when I was getting the same error.